# Drag and Drop sin arrastrar y boton de eliminar selección

Tags: javascript, html, css, uikit-3

Hola estoy buscando ayuda para resolver este problema. 
Intento implementar una vista de tarjetas donde el usuario desplaza el contenido a una zona donde genera su propia lista de contenido donde puede imprimir la hoja y eliminar de la lista.

El tema está que en la vista mobil la dinámica de desplazar se hace difícil y no funciona bien.

Lo que intento es implementar un botón para enviar a la zona de almacen y un boton de elimine esta tarjeta de eliminar de la lista pero no logro conseguirlo espero que me puedan ayudar.

**EJEMPLO:**

```js
// Boton para imprimir zona div 
function printDiv(areaImprimir) {
     var contenido= document.getElementById(areaImprimir).innerHTML;
     var contenidoOriginal= document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = contenido;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = contenidoOriginal;
}

// Faltaría agregar el envio automático de cada item
$(function(){
 //Obtenemos todos los elementos con clase uk-icon (botones)
  $(".uk-icon").each(function(){
    //En cada uno hacemos el bind al evento click
    $(this).click(function(){  
      //Buscamos su contenedor más cercano (uk-margin) y los movemos a #areaImprimir
      $(this).closest(".uk-margin").appendTo("#areaImprimir");      
    });    
  });
});
// Faltaria agregar Borrar selección
```

```css
.send-list{
  position: absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.17/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.17/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.17/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="uk-child-width-1-2@s" uk-grid>
    <div class="uk-background-secondary">
        <h4 class="uk-text-center uk-text-uppercase uk-background-default uk-padding-small">AGENDA</h4>
        <div  class="uk-padding-small" uk-sortable="group: sortable-group">
            <div class="uk-margin">
                <div class="uk-card uk-card-hover uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-card-small">
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-left uk-flex-middle">Item 1</span>
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-right send-list">
                  <a href="#" class="uk-icon-button uk-button-primary" uk-icon="forward"></a><span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-margin">
                 <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-card-small">
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-left uk-flex-middle">Item 2</span>
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-right send-list">
                  <a href="#" class="uk-icon-button uk-button-primary" uk-icon="forward"></a><span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-margin">
                 <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-card-small">
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-left uk-flex-middle">Item 2</span>
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-right send-list">
                  <a href="#" class="uk-icon-button uk-button-primary" uk-icon="forward"></a><span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-margin">
                 <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-card-small">
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-left uk-flex-middle">Item 4</span>
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-right send-list">
                  <a href="#" class="uk-icon-button uk-button-primary" uk-icon="forward"></a><span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- SE ALMACENAN AQUÍ -->
    <div>
        <div class="uk-text-center uk-text-uppercase uk-background-default uk-padding-small uk-margin-remove-bottom h4">ALMACEN 
          <a class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-float-right" onclick="printDiv('areaImprimir')" >
            <span uk-icon="print"></span>IMPRIMIR</a>
          <a href="#" class="uk-icon-button uk-button-primary uk-float-right uk-margin-right" uk-icon="trash"></a></div>
        <div id="areaImprimir" class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body uk-maring-right" uk-sortable="group: sortable-group">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya que uikit requiere jQuery te paso una solución con él.

La idea es obtener todos los `uk-icon`, recorrerlos con un `.each` y a cada uno hacerle el `bind` al evento click para que al pulsarlo se mueva de un contenedor a otro.

**Edito con la nueva pregunta**

```js
// Boton para imprimir zona div 
function printDiv(areaImprimir) {
     var contenido= document.getElementById(areaImprimir).innerHTML;
     var contenidoOriginal= document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = contenido;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = contenidoOriginal;
}

    $(function(){
 //Obtenemos todos los elementos con clase uk-icon (botones)
 $('a[uk-icon]').each(function(){
  //En cada uno hacemos el bind al evento click
  $(this).click(function(){  
   if($(this).attr("uk-icon")==="forward")
   {   
     //Buscamos su contenedor más cercano (uk-margin) y los movemos a #areaImprimir
     $(this).closest(".uk-margin").appendTo("#areaImprimir");      
     $(this).attr("uk-icon","reply");
   }
   else if ($(this).attr("uk-icon")==="reply")
   {
    //Si el botón es un reply es que queremos deshacer y volver a añadir al div "areaAgenda"
    $(this).closest(".uk-margin").appendTo("#areaAgenda");
    //Restablecemos el icono
    $(this).attr("uk-icon","forward");
   }
  });    
 });  
 //Si pulsamos borrar todo, obtenemos los .uk-margin y los ponemos en "areaAgenda" de nuevo con su icono correspondiente
 $("#btnBorrar").click(function(){
  $(".uk-margin").each(function(){
   $(this).appendTo("#areaAgenda");
   $($(this).find("a")).attr("uk-icon","forward");
  });
 });
});
```

```css
.send-list{
  position: absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:15px;
}
```

```html
   

 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.17/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.17/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.17/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
    <div class="uk-child-width-1-2@s" uk-grid>
    <div class="uk-background-secondary">
        <h4 class="uk-text-center uk-text-uppercase uk-background-default uk-padding-small">AGENDA</h4>
        <div  id="areaAgenda" class="uk-padding-small" uk-sortable="group: sortable-group">
            <div class="uk-margin">
                <div class="uk-card uk-card-hover uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-card-small">
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-left uk-flex-middle">Item 1</span>
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-right send-list">
                  <a href="#" class="uk-icon-button uk-button-primary" uk-icon="forward"></a><span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-margin">
                 <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-card-small">
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-left uk-flex-middle">Item 2</span>
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-right send-list">
                  <a href="#" class="uk-icon-button uk-button-primary" uk-icon="forward"></a><span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-margin">
                 <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-card-small">
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-left uk-flex-middle">Item 2</span>
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-right send-list">
                  <a href="#" class="uk-icon-button uk-button-primary" uk-icon="forward"></a><span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-margin">
                 <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-card-small">
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-left uk-flex-middle">Item 4</span>
                  <span class="uk-flex uk-flex-right send-list">
                  <a href="#" class="uk-icon-button uk-button-primary" uk-icon="forward"></a><span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- SE ALMACENAN AQUÍ -->
    <div>
        <div class="uk-text-center uk-text-uppercase uk-background-default uk-padding-small uk-margin-remove-bottom h4">ALMACEN 
          <a class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-float-right" onclick="printDiv('areaImprimir')" >
            <span uk-icon="print"></span>IMPRIMIR</a>
          <a id="btnBorrar" href="#" class="uk-icon-button uk-button-primary uk-float-right uk-margin-right" uk-icon="trash"></a></div>
        <div id="areaImprimir" class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body uk-maring-right" uk-sortable="group: sortable-group">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias @kiko_L funcionando perfectamente estaba pensando si es posible deshacer  los items que se van almacenando o mismo  borrar toda la selección?

Para borrar todo yo solo lo conseguiría un boton que refrescara toda la página ;(

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "borrar todo"? ¿A quitar todos los elementos o a eliminarlos de tu segundo contenedor? Respecto a deshacer los cambios puedes almacenar en un array los ids de los elementos que vas cambiando y luego, cada vez que le das a deshacer, obtener el id de ese array y moverlo al contenedor inicial. Si explicas un poco mejor lo de borrar todos (y actualizas la pregunta) actualizo mi respuesta.

Comment: Listo si no lo he entendido mal he actualizado el la pregunta inicial?
Basicamente es lo que tu bien dices quitarlos del segundo contenedor asi posibilitando la opción de que si no quieres esa tarjeta en la lista que selecionanste previamente la puedas eliminar.

Comment: He añadido los cambios. El deshace simplemente sería que cambiara el botón para volver al área de la agenda (le he añadido el id "areaAgenda") y el eliminar todas restaura los divs a dicho areaAgenda (como al principio)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Kiko_L